# Solution of the Cauchy problem $xu_x + yu_y = 0$, $u(x,y) = x$ on $x^2 +y^2 =1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

The Cauchy problem $xu_x + yu_y = 0$, $u(x,y) = x$ on $x^2 +y^2 =1$ has

1. a solution for $x ,y \in \Bbb R$
2. a unique bounded solution in $\{x ,y \mid (x,y) \neq (0, 0)\}$
3. an unique solution in $\{x ,y \mid (x,y) \neq (0, 0)\}$ but not bounded.

I have tried to solve this problem. Can anyone please check and tell me how to proceed further and which option(s) will be right?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $$v(r,\theta) = u(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$$

Then $$u_x = v_r\cos\theta - v_\theta r \sin \theta \\
 u_y = v_r\sin\theta + v_\theta r \cos \theta $$
$$xu_x + yu_y = v_r r\cos^2\theta - v_\theta r^2 \sin \theta \cos\theta \\
 +  v_r r\sin^2\theta + v_\theta r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta$$
$$
0 = xu_x + yu_y = r v_r
$$

Therefore $v_r = 0$ everywhere except possibly at the origin, and 
$$
v(r, \theta) = f(\theta)
\\ u(x,y) = f(\mbox{atan2 } (y/x) ) $$
where the atan2 function is the usual quadrant-aware arctangent (atan2 is in the third quadrant if $x$ and $y$ are both negative, etc).

Now if we impose the boundary conditions, the unique solution is 
$$
u(x,y) = f(\cos\left(\mbox{atan2 } (y/x) \right)
$$

This is a bounded function, but it is not defined at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ because on an arbitrarily small circle around the origin, ($u(x,y)$ takes on all values in $[-1,1]$.

So the answer is 2 - bounded everywhere but domain does not include the origin.

Comment: You could write the solution more conveniently as $u = \cos\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Can you please check my answer once again? I have made some changes. I really did not get what you have told. Can you please check and tell me what to do next?@Mark Fischler

Comment: Can you please check my answer once again? I have made some changes.  Can you please check and tell me what to do next?@Dylan

Answer (score 1):

From your notes, it's not quite clear (to me) what you have actually done, but what the PDE says is that $u$ must be constant on rays (half-lines) from the origin. Together with the given values on the unit circle, that should tell you anything you need to know about $u$.

Comment: I have applied the Cauchy's method for solving First order Pde.@Hans Lundmark

Comment: Can you please check my answer once again? I have made some changes. I really did not get what you have told. Can you please check and tell me what to do next?@Hans Lundmark

Answer (score 1):

Taking
$$
xu_{x}+yu_{y}=0\text{ with } u(x,y)=x \text{ on }x^{2}+y^{2}=1
$$

Due to the contour conditions we will consider the change of variables

\begin{align}
x & = r\cos\theta\\
y & = r\sin\theta
\end{align}

with

\begin{align}
dx & = dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta\\
dy & = dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta
\end{align}

we have
\begin{align}
u_{x} & = u_{r}\frac{dr}{dx}+u_{\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}\\
u_{y} & = u_{r}\frac{dr}{dy}+u_{\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dy}
\end{align}

Here from the characteristic curves

$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}=\tan\theta
$$

so we obtain

$$
xu_{x}+yu_{y}=0\iff2ru_{r}=0\implies u(r,\theta)=C+\Phi(\theta)
$$

Note that

\begin{align}
\frac{dr}{dx} & = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}\\
\frac{dr}{dy} & = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\\
\frac{d\theta}{dx} & = 0\\
\frac{d\theta}{dy} & = 0
\end{align}

Now with the boundary conditions

$$
u(1,\theta)=\cos\theta\implies\Phi(\theta)=\cos\theta\text{ and }C=0
$$

and finally

$$
u(r,\theta)=\cos\theta
$$

or in $(x,y)$ coordinates, $$du(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$$

Comment: I don't think the $C$ is necessary here, since a constant is also a function of $\theta$. Hence the general solution $u(r,\theta) = \Phi(\theta)$ is sufficient.

Comment: Can you please check my answer once again? I have made some changes. I really did not get what you have told. Can you please check and tell me what to do next?@Cesareo

Comment: Can you please check my answer once again? I have made some changes. I really did not get what you have told. Can you please check and tell me what to do next?@Dylan

Comment: As far as could see $\frac{x^2}{y^2}=u^2(1+\frac{x^2}{y^2})\Leftrightarrow x^2=u^2(x^2+y^2) \Rightarrow u = \pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$